# TSQL - CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON Not Returning Null?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, string-concatenation

I have had a look around and seem to have come across a strange issue with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I understand that with CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL = ON means that the following will always resolve to NULL

```
SELECT NULL + 'My String'
```

I'm happy with that, however when using this in conjunction with COALESCE() it doesn’t appear to be working on my database.

Consider the following query where MyString is VARCHAR(2000)

```
SELECT COALESCE(MyString + ', ', '') FROM MyTableOfValues
```

Now in my query, when MyString IS NULL it returns an empty (NOT NULL) string. I can see this in the query results window.

However unusually enough, when running this in conjunction with an INSERT it fails to recognise the CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL instead, inserting a blank ‘, ‘.

Query is as follows for insert.

```
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
INSERT INTO Mytable(StringValue)
SELECT COALESCE(MyString + ', ', '')
FROM MyTableOfValues
```

Further to this I have also checked the database and CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL = TRUE…

Comment: It seems that you have a comma too many in your parameterlist for COALESCE.  Try COALESCE(MyString + ', ', '') instead of COALESCE(MyString, + ', ', '').

Comment: Apologies Jakob, I misstyped that in the above example. The query was re-formatted for this question as I wasnt going to post all the column detail. You can consider (MyString + ', ', '') to be what I used. Sorry... I will edit the post.

Comment: Because, I am using contact on the string as I want to use the comma and a space at the end. With CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, shouldnt MyString + ', ' return a Null value therefore output ''. I certainly see this in the output window (results to grid in SSMS) but it doesn't work on the insert. - Edit, Caps.

Comment: Unable to reproduce (having corrected your sample query by adding `SET` in front of `CONCAT_...`) - it would be a lot easier if we were working with an actual query that *you* had run that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I realise that although the `COALESCE()` is checking for nulls the table has empty strings which I had not seen due to the way it was formatted. Therefore, (I feel a bit stupid) it is working as intended. I would need to opt out any empty strings from "MyTableOfValues".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NULLIF(MyString, '')` instead of just `MyString`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(MyString, '') + ', ', '') FROM MyTableOfValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

You're getting a ', ' because it's the first nonnull expression in your coalesce call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From some of the answers provided I was able to assertain a more in depth understanding of COALESCE().

The reason the above query did not fully work was because although I was checking for nulls, and empty string ('') is not considered null. Therefore although the above query worked, I should have checked for empty strings in my table first.

e.g.

```
SELECT COALESCE(FirstName + ', ', '') + Surname
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Joe' AS Firstname, 'Bloggs' AS Surname UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'Jones'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '', 'Jones'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob', 'Tielly'
) AS [MyTable]
```

Will return

```
FullName
-----------
Joe, Bloggs
Jones
, Jones
Bob, Tielly
```

Now row 3 has returned a "," character which I was not originally expecting due to a Blank but NOT NULL value.

The following code now works as expected as it checks for blank values. It works, but it looks like I took the long way around. There may be a better way.

```
-- Ammended Query
SELECT COALESCE(REPLACE(FirstName, Firstname , Firstname + ', '), '') + Surname AS FullName0
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Joe' AS Firstname, 'Bloggs' AS Surname UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'Jones'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '', 'Jones'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bob', 'Tielly'
) AS [MyTable]
```